# Compute median of column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, attributeerror, median

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
+-----------+------------+
|parsed_date|       count|
+-----------+------------+
| 2017-12-16|           2|
| 2017-12-16|           2|
| 2017-12-17|           2|
| 2017-12-17|           2|
| 2017-12-18|           1|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-20|           1|
+-----------+------------+
```

I want to compute median of the entire 'count' column and add the result to a new column.

I tried:

```py
median = df.approxQuantile('count', [0.5], 0.1).alias('count_median')
```

But of course I am doing something wrong as it gives the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'alias'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a column with `withColumn` because `approxQuantile` returns a list of floats, not a Spark column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('count_media', F.lit(df.approxQuantile('count',[0.5],0.1)[0]))

df2.show()
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|parsed_date|count|count_media|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
| 2017-12-16|    2|        2.0|
| 2017-12-16|    2|        2.0|
| 2017-12-17|    2|        2.0|
| 2017-12-17|    2|        2.0|
| 2017-12-18|    1|        2.0|
| 2017-12-19|    4|        2.0|
| 2017-12-19|    4|        2.0|
| 2017-12-19|    4|        2.0|
| 2017-12-19|    4|        2.0|
| 2017-12-20|    1|        2.0|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

You can also use the [`approx_percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#approx_percentile) / [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile_approx) function in Spark SQL:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('count_media', F.expr("approx_percentile(count, 0.5, 10) over ()"))

df2.show()
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|parsed_date|count|count_media|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
| 2017-12-16|    2|          2|
| 2017-12-16|    2|          2|
| 2017-12-17|    2|          2|
| 2017-12-17|    2|          2|
| 2017-12-18|    1|          2|
| 2017-12-19|    4|          2|
| 2017-12-19|    4|          2|
| 2017-12-19|    4|          2|
| 2017-12-19|    4|          2|
| 2017-12-20|    1|          2|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: thank you for looking into it. could you please tell what is the roll of [0] in  first solution: df2 = df.withColumn('count_media', F.lit(df.approxQuantile('count',[0.5],0.1)[0]))

Comment: df.approxQuantile returns a list with 1 element, so you need to select that element first, and put that value into F.lit

Comment: does that mean  ; approxQuantile , approx_percentile and percentile_approx all are the ways to calculate median?

Comment: yes. I prefer approx_percentile because it's easier to integrate into a query, without using `F.lit`.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.4+** has [**`median`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#median) for calculating accurate median (for small/mid-sized dataframes).

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2017-12-16', 2),
     ('2017-12-16', 2),
     ('2017-12-17', 2),
     ('2017-12-17', 2),
     ('2017-12-18', 1),
     ('2017-12-19', 4),
     ('2017-12-19', 4),
     ('2017-12-19', 4),
     ('2017-12-19', 4),
     ('2017-12-20', 1)],
    ['parsed_date', 'count'])

df.withColumn('median_of_count', F.expr('median(count) over()')).show()
# +-----------+-----+---------------+
# |parsed_date|count|median_of_count|
# +-----------+-----+---------------+
# | 2017-12-16|    2|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-16|    2|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-17|    2|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-17|    2|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-18|    1|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-19|    4|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-19|    4|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-19|    4|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-19|    4|            2.0|
# | 2017-12-20|    1|            2.0|
# +-----------+-----+---------------+
```